# group redundant object value into array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
["name: edward, subjectId:1, remark:passed",
"name: edward, subjectId:3, remark:passed",
"name: Jamie, subject:1, remark:excellent"]
```

Above is a messed up output which I have no power to control. I have to map it and clean that up. The ideal array object have to be like below :

```
[{name:"edward",subjectId:1,3,remark:"passed},{name:"Jamie",subjectId:1,remark:"excellent"}]
```

But for me it seems impossible because it doesn't have unique id for each record. I can compare the remark and group the subjectId properly, but what if it has a row that inserted on not the same date? Then my logic flawed. Any thought?

Comment: Is "edward" the same person in both instances? If he is, could you save the subject id in an array - `subjectId: [1, 3]`?

Comment: is it possible to have "edward" present at 2 different rows with 2 different subjectId like 1,3 as well as 2 different remark as "passed" and "excellent"?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Array.prototype.map()` ; `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(\w+)(?=:|,|$)/g` to match words followed by `":"`, `","` or end of string , replace with quoted string ; `JSON.parse()`

```js
var arr = ["name: edward, subjectId:1, remark:passed",
  "name: edward, subjectId:3, remark:passed",
  "name: Jamie, subject:1, remark:excellent"
];

var res = arr.map(function(val) {
  return JSON.parse("{" + val.replace(/(\w+)(?=:|,|$)/g, "\"$1\"") + "}")
});

console.log(res);

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is so close to being JSON, it's a shame you have to throw string manipulation at it!

```
var input = [
    "name: edward, subjectId:1, remark:passed",
    "name: edward, subjectId:3, remark:passed",
    "name: Jamie, subject:1, remark:excellent"
];

function makeJson(str) { // Deal with each of your input strings
    function wrapKeyAndVal(str) { // Wrap the key and value pairs in double quotes
        var key = str.split(':')[0].trim();
        var val = str.split(':')[1].trim();
        return '"' + key + '"' + ':' + '"' + val + '"';
    }
    return str.split(',').map(wrapKeyAndVal).join(',');
}

input = input.map(makeJson);

// Parse each string into an object
var output = input.map(item => JSON.parse("{" + item + "}"))

// You'll end up with an array of objects
console.log(output);
```